# Page conception : Php / Jquery / JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm looking for advice or comment about the way i created a php page.

I have 3 forms (step : 1, 2, 3) on the same page but i only show 1 at the time. After each submit i reload the page and check the current step. You can find below the way I created the page. I wonder if there is something wrong or if I made somthing not recommended.

It seems to workfine but i might be wrong or doing bad things. For exemple, can i use a php var in my javascript switch ?

```
<?php
include_once('header.inc.php'); 

//POST Step1
if(isset($_POST['nextstep12'])) {
        $_SESSION['step'] = 2;
}
//POST Step 2
if(isset($_POST['prevStep21'])) {
    $_SESSION['step'] = 1;
}   
if(isset($_POST['nextStep23'])) {
    $_SESSION['step'] = 3;
}

if (!isset($_SESSION['step'])) {
    $_SESSION['step']= 1;
}
?>
<body> 
    <?php if ($_SESSION['step'] == 1) { ?>
    <!-- STEP 1 -->
    <div id="Step1" class="row">
        <div class="form-container col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <form id="step1"  method="post" action="index.php">                                                 
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                        <label class="event" for="title"><?php echo T_("Title"); ?></label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="title" type="text" name="title" /> 
                    </div><!--//form-group-->
                </div>              
            </form>
        </div><!--//form-container-->
    </div><!--// STEP 1 -->

    <?php } else if ($_SESSION['step'] == 2) { ?>
    <!--// STEP 2 -->
        <div id="Step2" class="row">
            <div class="form-container col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <form id="Step2"  method="post" action="index.php">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                            <input class="form-control" id="autocomplete" onFocus="geolocate()" type="text" name="autocomplete"
                        </div><!--//form-group-->
                    </div>                                              
                </form>
            </div><!--//form-container-->
        </div><!--// STEP 2 -->
    <?php } ?>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        var curStep = <?php echo $_SESSION['step']; ?>;
        //STEP1 : DateTimePickers
        switch (curStep) {
            case 1:
                initDateTimePickers();
                initStep1Form();
                break;
            case 2:
                initGeolocate();
                initStep2Form();
                break;
        }

        // TOOLTIP (question mark)
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

        // Form Validate
        jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
          debug: false,
          focusInvalid: true
        });

        function initStep1Form () {
            jQuery("#eventFormSOne").validate({
                rules: {
                     "title":{
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 2,
                        maxlength: 105
                     }
                },
                messages: {
                    "event-title": "<?php echo T_("Title is required"); ?>"             
                }
            });
        }

        function initStep2Form () {
            jQuery("#eventFormSTwo").validate({
                rules: {
                     "place":{
                        required: false,
                        minlength: 0,
                        maxlength: 105
                     }   
                },
                messages: {
                    "place": "<?php echo T_("Place is requiered"); ?>"
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>

 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">    
    function initDateTimePickers() {

            var $inputEndDate = $( '#end-date' ).pickadate({
                min: true,
                max: undefined,
                onSet: function(thingSet) {
                    $("#Step1").validate().element("#end-date");
                    $("#eventFormSOne").validate().element("#end-time");
                }
            }),endPicker = $inputEndDate.pickadate('picker');

            var $inputBeginDate = $( '#begin-date' ).pickadate({
                min: true,
                max: undefined,
            }),beginPicker = $inputBeginDate.pickadate('picker');           

        }
 </script>

 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">    
    function initGeolocate() {
        // This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
        // of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

        var placeSearch, autocomplete;
        var componentForm = {
          street_number: 'short_name',
          route: 'long_name',
          locality: 'long_name',
          administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
          country: 'long_name',
          postal_code: 'short_name'
        };
        // [END region_geolocation]
    }

    function initAutocomplete() {
          // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
          // location types.
          autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
              /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')))
              ,{types: ['geocode']};
          // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
          // fields in the form.
          autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
    }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&signed_in=true&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
```

Any advice or comment will be appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Though Your code look fine . Just few things I wil add here:

1. You dont have to write the script tag again and again . 
   I mean this  `<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">`
2. Your last line  :

`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&signed_in=true&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>`

Should not be last ,,, since it loads some script ,.., have a habbit of loading it in `<head>` tag

3. You have used `async` and `defer` in script tag... I believe You should use any one .

   **Here are some general rules to follow:**

   *1. If the script is modular and does not rely on any scripts then use async.*

   *2. If the script relies upon or is relied upon by another script then use defer.*

   *3.If the script is small and is relied upon by an async script then use an inline script with no attributes placed above the async scripts.*

I will try to add more points if possible ,, I hope this will help you in future

Comment: That's exactly what i'm looking for. Thank you for taking some times to help me.
Do not hesitate to add more comments.